# How can I get emacs to chmod new files to executable if they have a certain extension?

Tags: emacs

I often write small perl scripts to solve various problem of to explore perl behavior.

I use templates for .pl files which is nice. it autopopulates the basics into my buffer.

A small annoyance is that whenever I do this, before running it, I have to 
 chmod ugo+x

Can I get emacs to do this automagically for me (based on the file extension)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the solutions offered on [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MakingScriptsExecutableOnSave), they key off the fact that the file begins with `#!`.  There's also a package that does this, [shebang.el](http://harts.net/reece/emacs/shebang.el) (which I happen to use).  You could easily change the code to make the condition that the file name extension be `.pl`, but looking for `#!` is probably more generic.

Comment: shebang.el works except my version of emacs (23.1.1) needs "prefix-function-name" to be replaced with "(and (boundp 'prefix-function-name) prefix-function-name)"

Answer (score 5):

Of the solutions on the page to which Trey has linked, by far the best is:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)
```

I've been using this for many years and have almost never needed to make a script executable by hand in that time.